# How to reset momentum on Impetus.js?

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

I have an HTML5/JavaScript SPA which uses Impetus
https://chrisbateman.github.io/impetus/
to let the user scroll back and forth a data graph.
The SPA allows for zoom in and out via a pinch gesture.

Problem is, while the user is pinching the screen I would like to prevent Impetus.js from kicking in.

Is there any way to reset the momentum or at least prevent Impetus from calling the callback while processing the pinching gesture?

**What I tried**

This is how I setup Impetus:

```
new Impetus({
    source: myCanvasWhereUserCanScroll,
    update: function(x,y){
        myDisplayLibrary.onMouseDrag(x, y);
    }
});
```

This is the callback inside my display library:

```
self.onMouseDrag = function(x, y){

    if(state == "PINCHING") return;
    else
    {
        // scroll the chart
    }
}
```

As you can see, I tried to solve the problem by preventing the callback from reaching the library itself. If the library is in `PINCHING` mode, the callback is ignored. It doesn't work because Impetus keeps the "momentum" of the scrolling which builds up while the user is pinching, so even after the state goes back to non-pinching mode (i.e. the user doesn't pinch anymore) I still could get some callbacks. End result: the chart moves after the zoom in, which is not expected and really confusing.

Comment: Have you tried `pause()` and `resume()` method inside impetus ?

Comment: @NarendraJadhav tried it Friday, looks promising.. need some more test because the problem is intermittent. If it solves the problem please answer the question and I'll accept it

Comment: Could you please provide a small working demo? in code snippet (HTML5/JavaScript SPA )

Comment: @NarendraJadhav I actually thought about it but it but in order to expose the problem I would need to add too much code which is NDA protected by my client. I don't know any other way of creating the problem without that specific code

Comment: If you can make small demo related to your problem then it's good, don't put specific code. Just an demo that can help to understand the problem